# Gazebo / Ros: How to create a camera plugin with pixel-level segmentation?

Tags: ros, robotics

I am looking to create a camera plugin where, at each pixel of the image, I'm able to output what object it belongs to, if any. I've struggled to find a solution to this problem. Any suggestions regarding where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

If u want to make a camera is Gazebo simulation than u have to use the sensor plugin or sensor element in ur robot sdf/urdf model like described [here,](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=sensor), U can find both type of camera their, depth and rgb. For example if u want a kinect sensor(camera) which contains both the rgb and depth image than u can use bolow sdf lines in ur robot model. Here when u run this code it will publish both rgb and depth datas as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkYRBFR3iqc):, here i've used ray sensor.

```
 <gazebo reference="top">
    <sensor name='camera1' type='depth'>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <visualize>1</visualize>
      <camera name='__default__'>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <depth_camera>
          <output>depths</output>
        </depth_camera>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name='camera_controller' filename='libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so'>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
        <frameName>/camera_link</frameName>
        <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <depthImageTopicName>depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.4</pointCloudCutoff>
        <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
        <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
        <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
        <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
        <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
        <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        <CxPrime>0.0</CxPrime>
        <Cx>0.0</Cx>
        <Cy>0.0</Cy>
        <focalLength>0.0</focalLength>
      </plugin>
    </sens

or>
      </gazebo
```